# What shape lens would allow correct image projection at an oblique angle? (anamorphic)

Tags: optics

If you wanted to project a slide projector's image on a table as opposed to the wall and you could not move, shift or tilt the components.  Just able to change the lens.

What would the lens combination that projects a correct image on the table look like?

Comment: [This are the theoretical explanations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheimpflug_principle) ans [this are the Scheimpflug lenses](http://www.opto-engineering.com/products/3d-macro-lens-MCSM).

Comment: great.  so we know what it's called but still no lens shape?